# Vision language detection

Tags: swift, macos, ocr, apple-vision

I'm using `Vision` provided by Apple to convert some images into text.
It's working well, but the problem I currently have is with Chinese characters.

I'm doing this currently:

```
let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: recognizeTextHandler)
request.recognitionLevel = .accurate
request.recognitionLanguages = try! VNRecognizeTextRequest.supportedRecognitionLanguages(for: .accurate,
revision: request.revision)
```

And it looks like it supports a bunch of latin languages along with Chinese.

`Vision` seems to be able to detect languages such as German just fine automatically, but I have to specify Chinese at the front of the `recognitionLanguages` property for it to work with Chinese.

Is there any way to automatically detect the language of the image?

Comment: Chinese is kind of special, because it only works with `.accurate`. It also takes much longer. The system probably prioritizes the other languages first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have to specify Chinese at the front of the recognitionLanguages property for it to work with Chinese

This is how it was designed. `.accurate` uses a ML-based recognizer, and because Chinese is really complex, it *must* come first. See WWDC21's [Extract document data using Vision](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10041/?time=482) at 8:02.

This also means that there is no way to automatically detect the language of the image.